# FacebookSDK , can any access token get information from any user who granted access?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im considering using the Facebook SDK in my swift app and I have been researching it but i cant find a clear answer to this question,

I understand that you can get public information,but for example..

1. userA gives access to all his photos(including private) to my app
2. userA then choses 4-8 Photos he wants displayed on my app
3. my app stores all the URL's or ID's of those photos
4. userB logs in with his AccessToken ,can he now get access to those photos since userA gave access to the app to read his photos?

An example of this is the Tinder app,How is the Tinder app storing their information since its the same as Facebook,is Tinder storing URL's and accessing them with an access token or are they storing the selected profile photos of the user on their own server?

I want to achieve the same effect as the Tinder app but obviously storing all the photos on my server takes a lot more space compared to just storing URL's,Any information would be helpful
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the userA photos then you need to access it through userA token. When you save that user into your system you have to save it with the right token so any consecutive call you make on behalf of that user have the right access.

So the  workflow will be:

1. userA gives access to all his photos(including private) to my app
2. you save userA access token
3. userA then choses 4-8 Photos he wants displayed on my app my app stores all the URL's or ID's of those photos
4. userB logs in with his AccessToken
5. userB wants to access userA photos
6. your application fetch those photos using the saved userA token and displays that to userB

Comment: thank you , but from what i read i think access tokens invalidate after 60 days unless the user logs in,so if userA doesn't use my app for 60 days doesn't that mean his profile photos are unreachable?